# Message handler life span

Tags: .net, nhibernate, messaging, cqrs, servicebus

What is the recommended lifespan of a message handler?

My current implementation is raising a few problems, especially when it comes to data access (NHibernate).

Our current implementation is as follows:

**Client Application (web)**
Sends messages to a queue (in memory, msmq, azure)

**Worker application (windows service)**
Polls the queues, and passes the messages to the registered handlers.

When we initialize the worker, we register our handlers. The handlers are lazily loaded (using `Lazy<T>`) so they are not created until the queue processor actually starts (on a different thread).

When the handlers *are* initialized, we fill out their dependencies and they sit in memory until the queue processor is shut down.

One issue we have is that we are now using a single NHibernate ISession for all the handlers on a queue processor. It seems that a better solution would be to recreate the handlers on each cycle of the queue processor, meaning that each handler can have it's own ISession.

What is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the handler is directly tied to the operation of handling a message their lifetime should be the same.

If you use some kind of unit of work (NHibernate ISession) it's probably best to have one per transport message as xelibrion sais. One transport message could contain more logical (application) messages which should be processed together if they arrived in the same physical message.

This is the way it's done in NServiceBus and NanoMessageBus.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Fortunately, StructureMap's nested containers came to the rescue in handling the NHibernate session, per message.

Comment: You also need to make sure that the TransactionScope ( used for queue transactions ) has the same lifetime as your unit of work, or better, it's part of it.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer session per transport message

Comment: xelibrion, why not write a technical reason to use a session per message? "I prefer" is not a great reason.